# Wired connection is not showing in the menu (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, connection, wired

Wired connection is not showing in the menu (ubuntu 14.04)

```
 ifconfig -a

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2994 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2994 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:379566 (379.5 KB)  TX bytes:379566 (379.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:3e:8e:33:3c:47  
          inet addr:192.168.247.103  Bcast:192.168.247.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a3e:8eff:fe33:3c47/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20434 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20608009 (20.6 MB)  TX bytes:2012596 (2.0 MB)
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to up your Ethernet port then it will show . press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> and run command

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

or

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

also enable `wired connection` and  `Networking` from `network manager` to get Internet.

if you still face problem then open file `/etc/network/interfaces` using

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

add line

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

then run command

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Answer (score -2):

If your PC is still now showing up the Ethernet adapter (Wired connection) although the cables are properly connected, it might be due to the hardware problem. The built-in network devices in some PCs do not support for Linux system (Ubuntu). Installing Network Interface Card (NIC) to your PC can start your ethernet connection right away.

Comment: It is ***highly unlikely*** that the built-in interface is not supported

Comment: @Greenonline I started to install ubuntu 20.04 in my new PC but only VPN and Network Proxy was appeared in the network setting. I tried with all the commands here to show up my ethernet connection but it did not work. Inserting NIC to a slot in PC solved it finally. Btw my connection was behind a proxy server.